# Renaming a hardcoded filename by adding a suffix but using Len to remove the original filename

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a hardcoded file "**C:\Results\Results.xls**" and am currently running it through a QTP test. If it fails I need to add "-Failed" to the end of the file and on success "-success". I am currently doing this using

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sResultFilename = ResultsPath & Day & sExcelFile
if iRowsFailed > 0 Then 
oFSO.MoveFile sResultFilename, sResultFilename & "-Failed.xls" 
Else
oFSO.MoveFile  sResultFilename, sResultFilename & "-Success.xls"
End if
```

Which gives the result on fail - "**C:\Results\Results.xls-Failed.xls**"

I would like to remove the superfluous middle **'.xls'**

I have tried using the Len function with

```
iLen = len(sResultFilename)
iLen1 = iLen - 4
sResultFilename = Mid(1, iLen1) 'can just do (1, ilen-4) but this easier to read
```

making the move file

```
oFSO.MoveFile sResultFilename & ".xls", sResultFilename & "-Failed.xls"
```

But on running this it does not even change the filename to the earlier result.

How can I reference the initial filename preferable without making another variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the appropriate methods when dealing with file names:

```
ResultsPath = "C:\Results"
sExcelFile  = "Results.xls"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFile(fso.BuildPath(ResultsPath, sExcelFile))
if iRowsFailed > 0 Then
  result = "Failed"
Else
  result = "Success"
End if
f.Name = fso.GetBaseName(f) & "-" & result & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Left()`

```
oFSO.MoveFile sResultFilename, Left(sResultFilename, Len(sResultFilename)-4) & "-Failed.xls"
```